# Downloading a text file as string

Tags: android, file, asynchronous, download, synchronization

I have to download a txt file from a URL and place its content inside of a string.
There's no need to store on the device the txt file and then read it, is there any way to avoid this?
Also, the task needs to be sync but I'm also interested in how it would be possible to perform it async.
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59167642/how-to-open-a-txt-file-from-internal-storage-in-a-textview-on-android-studio

Answer (score 3):

You can use [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)

```java
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String run(String url) throws IOException {
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .build();

  try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
    return response.body().string();
  }
}
```

Add this to the gradle

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.1")
```